# Sci-Kit module not importing in python

Tags: python, eclipse, scikit-learn, python-import

I am attempting to use the Scikit-learn Module in Python.

I installed it using pip in Terminal ( I am using a Mac). It imports fine in the shell, but when I do it in Eclipse I get the error message that the module is not found. I've looked everywhere online, many sites show it should be imported as "import sklearn" but it still will not import for me. Does anoyone know what I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the specific error message?

also, if you're pretty new to python and installing packages, I highly recommend you take a look at anaconda.  It's an entire packaged installer (that's free!) that comes with a hundred libraries installed, and compatibility for a few hundred more.

Comment: I am getting "ImportError: no module named sklearn"

Comment: can you confirm the directory in which its installed and the pythonpath are the same?